# Need to translate linux command to windows

Tags: linux, windows

I am having the following command line in linux :
echo -n "06 0E 2b 34 02 04 01 0A 0E 10" | xxd -p -r|nc -q0 127.0.0.1 11720
Can some one help me to translate it to one or more windows commands?

Comment: xxd turns the hex dump into binary, nc sends it to the network address specified. you can use `man xxd` and `man nc` to read up the fine print. Powershell might be a good candidate on windows to replicate that.

Comment: `nc`, isn't that `netstat` in Windows?